# How to reach variable outside the ng-repeat scope

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is possible to reach variable outside the ng-repeat scope?

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zcbhubrw/

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="section" ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
            <div class="slide" >
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="section-title">Selected Mobiles</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="container-fluid fix ver2">
                    <div class="col-md-3 work-thumb" ng-repeat="phone in phones">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="count = {{$index}}">
                            {{phone.name}}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <p>Count: {{count}}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

I need to reach the **{{count}}** variable for further usage.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to represent with `count`? Or what are you trying to do?

Comment: The number of objects in controller file.

Comment: Use array length for that ..`{{phones.length}}` unless you are filtering in display and need filtered length

Comment: It seems like you need to show current `$index` position of an item when clicked from the array?

Comment: But I use their pointers in other section of code. I try to link every link to its objects. For e.g.:
1.st link should point to Nexus S
2.nd -> Motorola XOMM
...

Comment: Please update question with exactly what it is you are wanting to do. Intent in last comment is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call a `function while clicking the list inside ng-repeat` like this

`<a href="#" ng-click="setCount($index)">`

and defining the function in controller

```
 $scope.setCount = function(index) {
    $scope.count = index;
} ;
```

and updating the count value when you click

Here is a working plunker with your code,

http://embed.plnkr.co/rAbanmAR2Chw3P501tDc/preview

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can create function in the controller to set the count or refer the parent scope from inside the ng-repeat

```
ng-click="$parent.count = $index"
```

> [using parent scope](http://jsfiddle.net/x1Le85ks/)
>
> [using function](http://jsfiddle.net/hj8grpwg/)