# How to show additional row in table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

is there any way to insert additional row in `ng-repeat` ? Here is the problem.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in content |pagination: currentPage*limit| limitTo: limit | filter: searchText ">
            <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
            <td>{{user.nazwisko}}</td>
            <td>{{user.data_urodzenia}}</td>
            <td>{{user.imie2}}</td>
            <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
            <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
            <td><i ng-click="showDetails()" class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
```

I have this table with repeating. In last cell there is a button that will trigger function to show more details of user. So what i need is, an additional row inserted under presented row.

```
<tr ng-repeat...></tr>
<tr ng-show="details">additional data row</tr>
```

and the controller

```
$scope.details = false;
$scope.showDetails = function(){
    if (!details) {
        $scope.details = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.details = false
    }
}
```

Any way to do this ? Tried few approaches and didn't worked out.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30288248/492258)

Answer (score 2):

You can either put the ng-repeat on the tbody, which will likely cause some issues with styling.

Or you can use ng-repeat-start/end. As of angular 1.2, you can repeat over elements which is pretty cool - to do this you can;

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="user in content |pagination: currentPage*limit| limitTo: limit | filter: searchText ">
        <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
        <td>{{user.nazwisko}}</td>
        <td>{{user.data_urodzenia}}</td>
        <td>{{user.imie2}}</td>
        <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
        <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
        <td><i ng-click="showDetails()" class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="details">additional data row</tr>
```

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Better than my answer with using technical sense than human sense  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your **ng-repeat** in `tbody` tag, then you can use your additional row on a new `tr` tag

like this below way

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="user in content |pagination: currentPage*limit| limitTo: limit | filter: searchText ">
        <tr> 
            <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
            <td>{{user.nazwisko}}</td>
            <td>{{user.data_urodzenia}}</td>
            <td>{{user.imie2}}</td>
            <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
            <td>{{user.imie}}</td>
            <td><i ng-click="showDetails()" class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           // your additional row
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

And one more thing, Your code is totally wrong

```
$scope.details = false;
$scope.showDetails = function(){
    if (!details) {
        $scope.details = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.details = false
    }
}
```

this above code will open all row, not particular row. So you need maintain with this by `Array of $index`

Comment: Well you are propably right, but i couldn't test it before :P. Thanks tho !