# angularjs nested ng-repeat child length outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested ng-repeat, and am trying to use the length of the filtered nested ng-repeat outside the parent ng-repeat.
However, the result is always 0 ,if it is a single ng-repeat I can get the result.
I have tried $parent.filtered but it is getting wrong results.

example below:

```
 <div>
            Filtered Count :{{filtered.length}}
            <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
                <div ng-repeat="letter in  filtered = (group.letters | filter:filters.search )  | orderBy:orderByAttribute:sortReverse ">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Thx,

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. You have several groups, each having a different number of filtered letters. Which of these numbers should be displayed?

Comment: You should have done all this in your controller

Comment: I need the total of filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filtered` is created in the scope of the `ng-repeat` directive, that is an isolate scope.

```
        <!-- PARENT SCOPE -->
        Filtered Count :{{filtered.length}}
        <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
          <!-- NEW SCOPE HERE -->
            <div ng-repeat="letter in  filtered = (group.letters | filter:filters.search )  | orderBy:orderByAttribute:sortReverse ">
              <!-- NEW SCOPE HERE -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

that property is not accessible from the outer scope, it's like trying to access the `$index` property of the `ng-repeat` from the outerscope.

You can bind the filtered array to an object on the outer scope (e.g. in the controller of the template)

```
$scope.parent = {}
```

then inside the directive append filtered to parent in order to have a hook to filtered from the outside.

```
<div ng-repeat="letter in  parent.filtered = (group.letters | filter:filters.search )  | orderBy:orderByAttribute:sortReverse ">

 </div>
```

then in the parent scope

```
Filtered Count :{{parent.filtered.length}}
```

doc: [angular ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> ngRepeat directive creates new scope

Comment: works great bu instead of var parent, I had to use $scope.parent={}; Thx

Comment: The thing is that it will not get the total of the filtered,it will get the total of the index inside the parent ng-repeat

Comment: @DanyNA i meant $scope.parent, just fixed it :) . the parent object is a hook which allows you to see the content of filtered, you should be able to get the total count of items along with the content.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer given by seenimurugan would be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288248/how-to-reach-variable-outside-the-ng-repeat-scope) and I have updated his fiddle to make it dynamic. 
Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hj8grpwg/2)

```
<div class="section" ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="section-title">Selected Mobiles</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid fix ver2">
            <div class="col-md-3 work-thumb" ng-repeat="phone in phones">
                {{setCount($index)}}
                <a href="#">{{phone.name}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Count: {{count}}</p>
</div>
```

@Contrller

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.phones = [{
            'name': 'Nexus S',
            'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        },
        {
            'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        }
    ];
});
```

I have used this code from the fiddle created by seenimurugan in the original answer